# Test styled component with Jest-Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, styled-components

How can I test if my `styled-component` has a specific CSS attribute-value pair?

Let's say my component is the following :

```
const myColor = '#111';

const Button = styled.button`
  background-color: ${myColor};
`;
```

And the test checks that the `'background-color'` attribute has the value `'#111'`.

The test runner is **Jest** and I use the testing utilities library **Enzyme**.

Answer (score 16):

The `toHaveStyleRule` function of [jest-styled-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-styled-components#tohavestylerule) solved my problem!

```
import 'jest-styled-components'

describe('<Button> component', () => {
  it('should have myColor', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Button />);
    expect(wrapper.find('Button')).toHaveStyleRule('background-color', myColor)
  });
});
```

Comment: what if a component with specificity hack needs to be tested, like that one `const Button = styled.button'
&& {
  background-color: ${myColor};
}';`
 `toHaveStyleRule` doesn't work in this case for me

Comment: Found the solution: adding `modifier: '&&',` to the `toHaveStyleRule` method worked for me, like that: 
`.toHaveStyleRule('background-color', myColor, { modifier: '&&' });`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I follow to write the test case for styled component to test css, It might help and easy to write

```
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";

describe("Styled Components", () => {
  it("<Button  /> should have the correct styles", () => {
    const component = renderer.create(<Button />).toJSON();
    expect(component).toHaveStyleRule("background-color", myColor);
  });
});
```

Thank You